# While and Do/While Loops break unexpectedly

Tags: c++, while-loop, do-while

This program is INTENDED to loop infinitely.... so if someone enters 5, it asks for another number (5 or 9), if he/she enters 9, it asks for either 5 or 9... ad infinitum.

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world! Enter a number" << endl;
    int x;
    cin >> x;

    while (x == 5)
    {
        std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "Try again, you got 5" << endl;
        cin >> x;

    }

    while (x == 9)
    {
        cout << "You got 9, try again mate" << endl;
        std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cin >> x;
    }
return 0;
}
```

But I don't understand when I switch numbers (like "5" to "9" and back to "5") the program just stops.

I think its because after Loop #1 and Loop #2 finish executing, the program never returns to either one and continues directly to "return 0," but I dont know how to make the program return to both loops.

PS: I've tried switching to do-while loops and taking the "cin" statements out of the brackets, but they dont solve the problem.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with C++ but I think the loop should be something like `while(has number){ if(num = 5){ do something } if(num = 9){ do something } }`.

Comment: "I want an infinite loop" *doesn't write an infinite loop* "What's wrong?" erm...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You must be a bit slow... that was exactly why I was asking this question. Thankfully it's been answered

Comment: @OpenTheCSV: Yes I am very slow and I never help anyone.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You were obviously very helpful on this question. Have a good day

Comment: @OpenTheCSV: There is more to Stack Overflow than "help". This is a Q&A repository for the ages and, as such, you are expected — nay, _required_ — to make your question useful for other people. This one does not satisfy that requirement. Stack Overflow is not your own private, free helpdesk. Thanks.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  I was asking people why my INTENDED infinite loop was NOT actuallly behaving like an infinite loop, and the people who answered it understood that. Surely, there will be thousands more people who will face a similar problem or have faced it before who might see this, and learn from it. I dont understand how this question isnt useful for others, since it focuses on such a basic concept.

Comment: Whether this helps anyone is up to each reader to decide for themselves

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit And 1 last thing, tell me where exactly in the rules (like the Help Center) it says people are REQUIRED, rather than RECOMMENDED, to make questions useful for others.

Comment: @OpenTheCSV: You have to apply _reading comprehension_ and read between the lines because there is no single sentence stating it, but anyone with half a brain who even partially understands what this site is will realise it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not giving the desired behaviour because when the second while loop ends, you are not repeating the process and the program ends.
So what you want is to loop until the user has entered some number other than `5` or `9`.
 In order to do that we are using `while` loop which runs to infinity and we use break to escape the infinite loop if the user enters some number different than `5` or `9`.
You can modify your code like this:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world! Enter a number" << endl;
    int x;

    while(1){
        cin >> x;
        std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        if(x == 5)
            cout << "Try again, you got 5" << endl;
        else if(x == 9)
            cout << "You got 9, try again mate" << endl;
        else
            break;        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Billy said in the comments, your logic is flawed. First of all, if you want an *infinite* loop, don´t loop as long as some number is equal to 5 or 9. Then, in the loop, just check what number it is to make make the correct output.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;

    cout << "Hello world! Enter a number" << endl;

    while(1)
    {
        cin >> x;
        std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        if(x == 5) cout << "Try again, you got 5" << endl;
        if(x == 0) cout << "You got 9, try again mate" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line: `std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`. 
With it, you won't read input.

In your example there is no infinite loop. I suggest calling a function for each value:

```
inline void five(int &x)
{
    std::cout << "Try again, you got 5" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> x;
}

inline void nine(int &x)
{
    std::cout << "You got 9, try again mate" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> x;
}

inline void other(int &x)
{
    std::cout << "Try again: ";
    std::cin >> x;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world! Enter a number" << std::endl;
    int x{};
    std::cin >> x;
    bool running{true};

    while (running) {
        if (x == 5) five(x);
        else if (x == 9) nine(x);
        else other(x);
    }
}
```